# Deformation of a Rigid Scheme is étale Locally Trivial.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

This question is from ex.III.9.10, Hartshorne. All scheme are finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $f: X \rightarrow T$ be a flat projective morphism from $X$ to a nonsingular curve $T$. Assume that there is a closed point $t \in T$ s.t. $X_t \sim \mathbb{P}^1_k$.

Then we need to show that there is a nonsingular curve $T'$ and a flat morphism $g: T' \rightarrow T$ whose image contains $T$ and $X' = X \times_T T'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_{T'}$.

By flatness and smoothness of the fibre of $t$, we know that $f$ is smooth in a neighbourhood of every point of $X_t$. But the singular locus is closed and its image by $f$ is closed not containing $t$. Hence we have a neighbourhood $U$ of $t$ s.t. $f^{-1}(U)$ is in the smooth locus, i.e. $f: f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$ is smooth. Now by flatness $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is torsion free hence flat and locally free. By formal function theorem we know that it is of rank one. So every fibre is smooth connected curve of arithmetic genus $0$, which must be $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Now we have reduced to the situation of a smooth family of $\mathbb{P}^1$ over a smooth curve. It remains to find the suitable local base $T'$.

Moreover, I wonder whether we can choose $g$ to be étale. It seems reasonable since étaleness is a reasonable replacement of analytically localness. And when a scheme is rigid, I don't wish that it can be trivialized only after ramified base change.

Comment: just to be sure: "curve" does not mean complete, correct?

Comment: @peterag Yes. We just need to work in a local patch.

Comment: How are you doing on this? With help from theorem 3 a) of https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-8/issue-1/Characterization-and-algebraic-deformations-of-projective-space/10.1215/kjm/1250524176.full, I think the point is that if $K$ is the function field of $T$, then there is a finite extension $L/K$ such that $(X\otimes K)(L)\not=\emptyset$ (which is clearly true).

Comment: @peterag I post an answer. I don't know whether it is similar to your idea. You may check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to find a section $s: T \rightarrow X$ after base change.

Such a section is proper, hence defines a divisor $D$ in $X$. Since it is a section, it intersects each fibre transversely at exactly one point, hence its restriction as a divisor to each fibre is $\mathcal{O}(1)$, whose linear space of global sections is of dimension $2$. By the formal function theorem, or some arguments with upper semicontinuity, $f_*\mathcal{L}(D)$ is locally free of rank $2$. We can choose $T$ small enough s.t. $f_*\mathcal{L}(D)$ is free. This means that $\mathcal{L}(D)$ has two global sections.

Now we need to carefully choose two sections to let them defines a appropiate morphism $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_T$. Global sections of $f_*\mathcal{L}(D)$ and of $\mathcal{L}(D)$ are $1$-$1$ correspondent. Since we can let $f_*\mathcal{L}(D)$ being free, we can let $s_1, s_2$ be two sections of it s.t. they are linearly independent (as two vectors in $f_*\mathcal{L}(D)_t/m_tf_*\mathcal{L}(D)_t$). Then these two sections corresponding to two sections of $\mathcal{L}(D)$ s.t. their restriction to each $X_t$ is linearly independent, which means that they have no common zero, the linear system they span is base point free and the corresponding morphism from $X_t$ to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is an isomorphism.

So these two sections have no intersection since their restriction to each $X_t$ doesn't. This means they are base point free and define a morphism $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_T$ which is an isomorphism restricting to each $X_t$. Now each $X_t$ and $T$ are orthogonal and $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_T$ is relative to $T$, this morphism must be smooth of degree one, hence an isomorphism (This argument must be a little vague. But if you are familiar with scheme theory, or III.10 of Hartshorne, you know what I am saying. See for example, III.10.4.).

Now it remains to find the section. Let $x \in X_t$ be a closed point. Denote the uniformiser of $\mathcal{O}_{t,T}$ also by $t$. By smoothness, $t \neq 0 \in m_x/m^2_x$. Then $t$ locally defines a smooth curve $t: T' \hookrightarrow X$ and $f\circ s: T' \rightarrow T$ is unramified at $x$. Shrinking $T'$ s.t. $f\circ s$ is étale. Then $T'$ is the desired local base since the locally closed embedding $t$ is lifted to a closed embedding which is a section after base change.

Comment: +1, obviously. The thing that has been bothering me, I think from the first day you posted your question, is the throw-away Note in Hartshorne, midway down p. 369, immediately after the definition of (geometrically) ruled surface, is that in fact there should have been a $T$ section of $X$ (i.e., $X(T)\not= \emptyset$). So at worse we would have needed to take $T'$ an open  of $T$ - no "extension" $T'\to T$ necessary. (cont)

Comment: See Hartshorne chap V lemma  2.1 + prop 2.2. I hadn't want to mention this because a) shame b) I was wondering whether hypotheses in the def of surfaces mattered c) I hadn't spent the time to see - and, assuming that I was smart enough to succeed - that Tsen's theorem applied

Comment: @peterag If I understand right, the note is saying  that if we use another definition of ruled surfaces (which doesn't require existence of section but requires other extra properties), for example as in Shafarevich, we can by using Tsen's lemma deducing that two definition are equivalent, or saying that assume the definition by Shafarevich, we can find a section for ruled surface. This doesn't mean that every surface with fibre $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a ruled surface, i.e. having a section.

Comment: Right - so in the context of my c) above I had in fact wanted to find/think of (or rule out!) such a surface...